# Translation from parsley.js throws error and is not working

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

We need to translate our form errors from english in to german, french, italian, spanish and chinese.

For that we link the specific parsley file into our footer after the normal parsley.js file.

This all works perfect.

```
Parsley.addMessages('de', {
  defaultMessage: "Die Eingabe scheint nicht korrekt zu sein.",
  type: {
    email:        "Die Eingabe muss eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse sein.",
    url:          "Die Eingabe muss eine gültige URL sein.",
    number:       "Die Eingabe muss eine Zahl sein.",
    integer:      "Die Eingabe muss eine Zahl sein.",
    digits:       "Die Eingabe darf nur Ziffern enthalten.",
    alphanum:     "Die Eingabe muss alphanumerisch sein."
  },
  notblank:       "Die Eingabe darf nicht leer sein.",
  required:       "Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld.",
  pattern:        "Die Eingabe scheint ungültig zu sein.",
  min:            "Die Eingabe muss größer oder gleich %s sein.",
  max:            "Die Eingabe muss kleiner oder gleich %s sein.",
  range:          "Die Eingabe muss zwischen %s und %s liegen.",
  minlength:      "Die Eingabe ist zu kurz. Es müssen mindestens %s Zeichen eingegeben werden.",
  maxlength:      "Die Eingabe ist zu lang. Es dürfen höchstens %s Zeichen eingegeben werden.",
  length:         "Die Länge der Eingabe ist ungültig. Es müssen zwischen %s und %s Zeichen eingegeben werden.",
  mincheck:       "Wählen Sie mindestens %s Angaben aus.",
  maxcheck:       "Wählen Sie maximal %s Angaben aus.",
  check:          "Wählen Sie zwischen %s und %s Angaben.",
  equalto:        "Dieses Feld muss dem anderen entsprechen."
});

Parsley.setLocale('de');
```

The problem is, that the function setLocale at the bottom resolves in an error:

```
parsley.js:631 Uncaught Error: de is not available in the catalog
    at ValidatorRegistry.setLocale (parsley.js:631)
    at Base.window.Parsley.(/anonymous function) [as setLocale] (http://domain.tld/Resources/Public/Js/main.js?1554899096:29313:31)
    at Object.window.ParsleyValidator.(/anonymous function) [as setLocale] (http://domain.tld/Resources/Public/Js/main.js?1554899096:29320:57)
    at Function.initialize (ParsleyCustomized.js:26)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:45)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3534)
    at process (jquery.js:3602)
```

How can we fix this error and make the translations work?

Thanks for answer

Comment: Are you sure that `Parsley.setLocale(&#39;de&#39;);` is beign called after the addMessages?

Comment: Definitely should work...

Comment: And it does... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNpNzd?editors=101&editable=true
You are probably also calling `setLocale` from somewhere else

Comment: If we call setLocale, parsley thinks its undefined.

Comment: Hey @8iJohnny69 what parsley thinks is undefined?

Comment: @ShaharShokrani we fixed it now. The problem was, that we embedded parsley.js before the language-parsley.